# If I can't vote for my posts, why do I see voting buttons for my posts?

Tags: feature-request, voting

This seems a no-brainer: Remove voting buttons for logged-on user's posts.

If there were no buttons on my posts, there wouldn't be a need for the "You can't vote for your own post" message, because it would be impossible to vote for your own post.

---

The way it currently stands is actually nonsensical, because you *can* vote for your own post - there's a button right there and I can click it - but *when* I vote for my post I get an error message.

Put another way, there's an active control presented to the user that will *always* and can *only* produce an error. I'm not a UX design expert, but that doesn't sound like good design to me.

---

Notwithstanding a backend check to prevent malicious calls.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226360/why-do-vote-up-and-vote-down-buttons-show-up-on-ones-own-answers
which links to http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53986/why-are-vote-buttons-on-stack-exchange-shown-when-they-cant-be-used and http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items on the UX site. Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174775/you-cannot-vote-for-yourself-so-why-give-me-the-option, which also references [the same blog post as that UX post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/). Conspiracy!

Comment: @shog How about greyed out then?

Comment: I think the intent here is to *not* discourage you from clicking, since when you click you get an explanation for why you can't vote. Contrast with the UI areas that *are* greyed out (edit comes to mind...) where - even though you can still get an explanation by clicking / hovering - folks instead come here to ask why they can't click. (and yes, we're terribly inconsistent here, probably because different people designed different parts of the UI and didn't compare notes / thought they knew better / just didn't care)

Comment: @shog I still don't think it's a good idea. I don't think it takes a genius to figure out why there are no voting buttons on your own posts. Have you A/B tested it?

Comment: @Shog any chance to explain the rejection of the original feature request with an answer there?